# expose c# object data through ODBC driver or any other alternative ways?

Tags: c#, odbc, powerbi

I'm developing an application which can provide data from c# object to other applications like Power BI/Excel. Kindly suggest me, how can I handle this without violating data security.

Comment: Hi. Welcome to SO please read how to write a good question and follow the guidelines. Thank you

Comment: You could expose a WebService and consume it as explained [here](http://www.dotnetspider.com/resources/19-STEP-BY-STEP-Consuming-Web-Services-through-VBA-Excel-or-Word-Part-I.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The best way to expose data to Power BI, Excel, Tableau, etc. is through ODBC. There are other alternatives, but none that work across a wide range of BI tools. Since you're pulling in C# objects, I would suggest you look at the SimbaEngine SDK (http://www.simba.com/drivers/simba-engine-sdk/) which would allow you to write an ODBC driver in C# (http://cdn.simba.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/05/Build-a-C-ODBC-Driver-in-5-Days4.pdf), making it easy to connect to your C# objects.

Comment: Simba SDK is licensed software. Is there any opensource software available to solve this issue?